# Highchart bubble chart with same value(x,y) but different size(z) is not showing tool tip for inner bubble

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Issue**: I have to create a bubble chart using Highcharts lib. In the requirement we have two data points that have same value for x and y but different value for z. Now the bubbles are plotted fine but when i hover mouse over the completely overlapped bubbles it just shows  tooltip for the outer bubble and i cannot mouse over the inner bubble.

The outer bubble have greater z value than the inner bubble

Outer bubble values are

```
{
            "y": 5.5,
                "showInLegend": false,
                "borderColor": "",
                "enableMouseTracking": false,
                "sliced": false,
                "selected": false,
                "x": 112.3333333,
                "z": 3
        },
```

Inner bubble values are

```
{
            "y": 5.5,
                "showInLegend": false,
                "borderColor": "",
                "enableMouseTracking": false,
                "sliced": false,
                "selected": false,
                "x": 112.3333333,
                "z": 2
        }
```

Please refer the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/bhupendrasinghnegi/e2v0z3ez/1/ here for replicating the issue

Comment: It is related with fact that bubbles shapes overlapped and "tooltip point layer" gets the highest level (single point). It is default in SVG.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Thanks a lot but i can see we can achieve this, please refer the fiddle below, this is what i need, do i need to turn on or off certain properties of bubble chart?

http://jsfiddle.net/bhupendrasinghnegi/kqdrx1uo/

Comment: Ok in this case it works, but when the biggest covers smaller, then tooltip will show only single value.